# Java for-loop never terminates

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am trying to create a basic for loop that adds the elements of a temporary List to the main ArrayList. This causes my Android App to crash repeatedly.

```
    for (int i = 0; i<tempFavList.size();i++){
        Log.v("MyApp",Integer.toString(tempFavList.size()));
        favourites.add(tempFavList.get(i).toString());
    }
```

Some debugging showed that `tempFavList.size()` is equal to 2 before the for loop is called, but goes to infinity when the for loop is called (well at least to +500,000 before the App crashes). The list `tempFavList` is a List that is pulled from a Parse database using the code `tempFavList = currentUser.getList("favourites");`

I am fairly confused why the for size of the temporary List is increasing once the for loop is called, as I am not adding any items in the for loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it possible that `favourites` and `tempFavList` actually refer to the same object?

Comment: try printing the `tempFavList.size()` and `favourites.size()` inside the loop. see what you will get

Comment: debugging tip - try running this loop without changing THAT array. See if it works. Then try to figure out why THAT array is changing.

Comment: My guess is that you declared `tempFavList` as `tempFavList = favourites`. Note that this statement will **not** make a copy of your list: these two objects point to the same reference, so everything you add to `tempFavList`, is being added to `favourites` too

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, could you explain to me how this would occur? `tempFavList` is declared using `List<Object> tempFavList;`, then initialized through the parse command posted in the original. `favourites` is created using `public static ArrayList<String> favourites = new ArrayList<String>();` and is first used again in the code in the original comment

Comment: @ImmerAllein: I tried this, and both size's are increasing at a similar rate (although they are not the same, as before the for-loop `favourites.size()` equals 0 and `tempFavList.size()` equals 2.


@RichardLeMesurier: Thanks for the tip. I tried this, and the problem did not occur. This would suggest to me that this line is the issue, but I am still not clear why it is.

Comment: Why don't you clone tempFavList because it is an object and refers to the same object favorites, with clone actually you create a new object that is exactly the same but with different reference.

Comment: moneymango - it's impossible for me to comment on how you would happen to have made these two variables refer to the same object, without seeing more of your code than  you've provided.  But if you step through this code with a debugger, you'll certainly see whether the two references are the same, and you'll also be able to see what is causing `tempFavList` to change.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
final int tempSize = tempFavList.size();

for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have solved the problem. I am still not certain how or where the lists ended up referring to the same object, but this will have to do for now.

Comment: if you do System.out.println(favourites). whats in the list? 2 elements or 4?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is what I think you are doing 95% of the code I post here is probably what you have

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Temp {
    static ArrayList<String> favourites = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myGuiltyList= CurrentUser.getList("favourites");
        for (int i = 0; i < myGuiltyList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("myInnocentList size = " + favourites.size());
            favourites.add(myGuiltyList.get(i));
            if (myGuiltyList.size() == 1000) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static class CurrentUser {
        public static List<String> getList(String listName) {
            favourites.add("1");
            favourites.add("2");
            favourites.add("3");
            if (listName.equals("favourites")) {
                return favourites;
            }
            else return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the static list you have named favourites is actually the SAME list you get when you call the `CurrentUser.getList("favourites");` line. 
So they are actually the same list and you add element to the same list and the size of the list increases with every loop and the loop will never stop cos the size of the list will never be smaller than i cos they increase with the same ratio 
:D

Comment: `currentUser` is actually a ParseUser object, which is created using the code `ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();`


The line `tempFavList = currentUser.getList("favourites");` returns the column with the key "favourites" from the ParseUser currentUser. This "favourites" is just a string key, and is not the same as the favourites list.

Comment: Your error is 100% an error of 2 lists referencing the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Use iterators to iterate:

```
for (Object o : tempFavList){
    Log.v("MyApp",Integer.toString(tempFavList.size()));
    favourites.add(o.toString());
}
```

It will most likely throw an exception, if collection is modified while iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Iterator iterator = tempFavList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{ favourites.add(iterator.next());}
```